# Por que é que «gatos» e «gralhas» são erros tipográficos?

Tags: etimologia

***Gato***, para além do simpático animal, pode designar um erro de tipografia [(Aulete 13)](http://www.aulete.com.br/gato) e, pelo menos em Portugal, também um engano num manuscrito [(Priberam 9 e 10)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gato). As pobres das ***gralhas***, uns pássaros da família dos corvos, partilham a sorte dos gatos ([Aulete 3](http://www.aulete.com.br/gralha) e [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gralha)). Em Portugal também podemos *engatar* contas [(Priberam 8)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/engatar).

Quando é que *gato* e *gralha* passaram a ter estes significados? Há alguma razão plausível para isso?

Podem ver e ouvir [aqui a gralha de bico vermelho](http://www.avesdeportugal.info/pyrhoc.html) e mais a [gralha preta aqui](http://www.avesdeportugal.info/corcrn.html) e ainda a [gralha de nuca cinzenta aqui](http://www.avesdeportugal.info/cormon.html).

[image]

Comment: @JorgeB. Ah, descobriste uma gralha. Mas olha que era uma gralha bem apropriada.

Comment: Não me digas que foi propositada... Foi?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não, não foi. Descobri-a agora quando fui ver o que tinhas feito.

Comment: Curiosidade: no Brasil, gralha é somente o animal, entretanto **Gato** pode significar (além do animal, claro) um desvio ilegal dos cabos de telefone, TV, luz, etc. Ex: "O vizinho fez um gato para poder usar a TV a cabo." `:)`

Comment: Enquanto engenheiro electrotécnico, estou muito habituado a procurar "gatos" quer no código quer em circuitos/placas electrónicas. Para nós, também pode significar "bugs".

Comment: Em Portugal, Gato e Gralha é utilizado quando algo no conteúdo não é coerente. Não necessáriamente um erro de ortografia.

Comment: @Carlos, no Portugal que eu conheço, *gato* e *gralha* são usados tal como descrevi acima e como descrito nos dicionários: troca ou omissão de letras ou palavras, letras ou palavras repetidas ou a mais; normalmente fruto de descuido, não de ignorância.

Comment: Esses não são os únicos significados de "gralha". "Gralha" é ainda usado para se referir a uma pessoa tagarela/barulhenta, por alusão ao som estridente que a ave faz (talvez seja possível que uma "gralha" no texto seja considerada um "erro" por também fazer "barulho" indesejado, mas estou a conjeturar)

Comment: @Rye, bem visto. Quem sabe se foi por aí. Em relação ao *gato*, como *engatar* é prender uma coisa a outra, já me passou pela cabeça que o *gato* tipográfico tivesse que ver com carateres tipográficos "engatados", presos um no outro por engano.

Comment: Já ouvi *gralha* para erro, lapso, sobretudo tipográfico, tanto que nem sabia do animal. Mas *gato* é nova.

Comment: @Schilive, *gato* vem no [Mchelis (29, 30)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/gato/) também. Então aí, uma pessoa muito tagarela também não é 'gralha'?

Comment: @Jacinto, agora que vi a tua pergunta. Sim, pessoas tagarelas são gralhas aqui, mas isto se vê mais de gente mais velha, pelo tudo que conheço.

Comment: Jacinto, será que o "gato" vem da expressão "aqui há gato..."? Acho esta teoria improvável mas plausível.