# Qual a origem de "gato" para expressar atração física?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

"Gato" pode ser o siamês, o persa ou o *bobtail*. Vi também que pode se referir a [instalações clandestinas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/qual-a-origem-da-express%C3%A3o-gato-para-se-referir-a-instala%C3%A7%C3%B5es-clandestinas).

Mas existe também o uso dessa maneira:

> Aquela menina é uma gata!

Quando existe atração ou admiração física por alguém o termo "gato" é utilizado.

Qual a origem da expressão "gato" para se referir a pessoas atraentes?

Comment: E ainda pode ser um [erro tipográfico](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/por-que-%C3%A9-que-gatos-e-gralhas-s%C3%A3o-erros-tipogr%C3%A1ficos). Parece-me que aqui só será possível tentar encontrar os primeiros exemplos desse uso e pouco mais.

Comment: uma referência->https://queloucurablog.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/por-que-chamamos-uma-pessoa-bonita-de-gata/

Comment: Outra referência https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/gato-e-gata-em-referencia-a-pessoas-bonitas/33598

Comment: Gata = bonita, atraente. Pessoas comparam pessoas com coisas que consideram bonitas ou feias.  Até com pão "Você é um pão".

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, parece ser uma gíria tipicamente Brasileira:

> O uso de gato e gata no sentido que refere é conhecido e tem difusão,
>   mas ainda é considerado como típico do português do Brasil. Não temos
>   fontes que esclareçam como surgiu essa aceção da palavra, mas supomos
>   que tenha sido por metáfora, equiparando a sedução de uma pessoa ao
>   comportamento voluptuoso e muitas vezes selvagem dos felinos.

Fonte: [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/gato-e-gata-em-referencia-a-pessoas-bonitas/33598)

E tem seu uso popularizado nos anos 60:

> ANOS 60 aldeia global (nosso mundo), bacana (bom, bonito), boa pinta
>   (de boa aparência), boazuda (mulher bonita), bolinha (estimulante),
>   cafona (feio), calhambeque (carro velho), cara (indivíduo), carango
>   (carro), certinha (mulher bonita), chapa (amigo), dar tábua
>   (recusar-se a dançar), duca (ótimo), é fogo! (é difícil), é uma brasa,
>   mora! (é espevitada, danada esticada (passar por vários restaurantes e
>   bares noturnos),fossa (depressão, crise existencial),gamar (namorar),
>   gata (mulher bonita), grana (dinheiro), jovem guarda (movimento
>   artístico musical), legal! (ótimo!),mancar (desrespeitar compromisso),
>   minissaia (saia curta), paca (muito), pão (homem bonito), papo firme
>   (conversa séria), papo furado (conversa boba), pé de chinelo (pessoa
>   sem expressão), pelego (líder sindical governista), pode vir quente
>   que estou fervendo (excitada), pra frente (moderno), quadrado
>   (conservador), sifo (deu-se mal), sifu (deu-se mal), tremendão (rapaz
>   bonito), uma brasa, mora (bom, ótimo!), ziriguidum (samba no pé,
>   molejo de mulata).

Fonte: [Gírias: na boca de jovens e adultos](https://revistadeciframe.com/2011/10/18/girias/)

E segundo o livro [De onde vem as palavras: origens e curiosidades da língua portuguesa](https://books.google.com/books?id=P3JxBAAAQBAJ&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_navlinks_s) de Deonísio da Silva, o uso é devido a união da bela e da fera domesticada.

[image]

Comment: Aos 60 é coerente com o que eu vi no Google Books; o primeiro exemplo que encontrei foi dos anos 70; na linguagem oral já deveria existir antes, naturalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que a associação da palavra GATO(A) com relação à beleza deve ter vindo da sensualidade que esse animal tem. A forma de andar e de olhar do felino é muito sensual, diferente do cachorro, que parece ser um animal mais alegre.

Answer (score -3):

Gata - Era uma gíria criada na década de 50 (1950) para ofender mulheres que tinham mais de um filho de pais diferentes, depois(sei lá quando...) passou a ser um elogio.

Bacana = Alude ao deus romano BACO, o deus do vinho; termo usado para se referir a festas regadas a vinho e bebidas alcóolicas, e coisas ligadas à putaria.

CDF = gíria criada no colégio Estadual na década de 80, em Belem do Pará, para se referir aos que sentavam na CADEIRAS DA FRENTE, ou sejam, os pucha-saco do professor mas também aos que se interessavam pela aula; O oposto são os TDF (turma do fundão).